# Unexpected condition on http://127.0.0.1:8887/#/home: Could not find value for language

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the next error message when i click on an href:

Unexpected condition on http://127.0.0.1:8887/#/home: Could not find value for language

I'm using ngRoute. This is my index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="pagoApp">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Paga-Facturas</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="app/componentes/css/paga-stilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<head>

    <base href="/">

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/list">List</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/xml2json.js"></script>
<script src="app/pagapp.js"></script>
<script src="app/componentes/listado-componente/pago-components.js"></script>
<script src="app/componentes/listado-componente/home-component/home-component.js"></script>
<!--<script src="app/componentes/autorizar-componente/autorizar.js"></script>-->
<script src="app/factory/pago-factories.js"></script>
<script src="app/routes/routes.js">

</body>
</html>
```

And my routes file:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('pagoApp')
        .config(config);


    config.$inject = ["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider"];
        function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

            $routeProvider
                .when('/home',{
                    template: '<home></home>',
                    controller: 'homeCtrl',
                })

                .when('/list',{
                    template: '<paga-facturas></paga-facturas>',
                    controller: 'payCtrl'
                })

                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home',
                });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        }

        })();
```

When i click on Home or List, shows the metioned message, and redirect me to my Index of current directory. Anyone knows why i'm getting this error message?

Comment: You don't use `#` in url when you are using `html5Mode` but you also must configure server for html5Mode to account for virtual paths

Comment: have u tried moving all the essential angular files to the `<head>` ?  to me it looks a bit strange that there are so many `ng` properties and the angular scripts are in the end of the html file...if you check the plunker here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView they do what i mention

Comment: @DrNio putting script files at end of body is a best practice for page load speed.

Comment: Thanx for your comments. I've found my error.

Comment: what was the issue ?

Comment: i didn't close de <script> for the routes file ¬¬. Thanx again for your help